# How do I get rid of unneeded space in css (from PHP code)

Tags: php, css, html-table, line-breaks

I find two html line break entries inserted between my div element and table elements. I don't know how to get rid of them. The unwanted space is labelled red in the attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]
My relevant table stylings are as follows:

```
              table {
                  font-family: 'Arial';
                  margin: 25px auto;
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                  border: 1px solid #eee;
                  border-bottom: 2px solid #00cccc;
                  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
                }
                .alt { background: #D0FFFF; color: #FFFFFF; }
                table tr:hover {
                  background: #f4f4f4;
                }
                table tr:hover td {
                  color: #555;
                }
                table th, table td {

                  color: #5C5456;
                  border: 1px solid #eee;
                  font-size: 12px;
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                table th {
                  background: #00cccc;
                  color: #fff;
                  text-transform: uppercase;
                  font-size: 12px;
                  font-weight: bold;
                }
                table th.last {
                  border-right: none;
                }
```

Basically this is code I lifted elsewhere from the net as I'm not very knowledgeable with CSS yet.

My code has:

```
$dumpout .= "<div><p class=\"pi\">Dear ....</p></div>
                    <div><table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                       {the rest of the stuff} ";
```

So clearly I do not have line breaks in the code. How can I get rid of this space?

Also what code can make the table expand and fill out the entire width of the screen as opposed to the little middle section? Please note, even though I display in browser to troubleshoot, the final output is being sent in an email.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines saying 
 and you will be done

Comment: I have edited to show my code does not have line breaks. Strange how its been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
- <body>
+ <div>
- <div>
      <br>
      <br>
    - <table>
       + <thead>
```

In this code you are using 
 break tags which causes for new line. Just remove 
 tags and it will be fine

Comment: it's not that simple. My code doesn't have the break tags. Take a look at the section of my post that says "My code has:..." $dumpout .= "<div><p class=\"pi\">Dear ....</p></div>                     <div><table>                       <thead>                         <tr>                        {the rest of the stuff} "; somehow the breaks are being inserted between "<div><table>"

Comment: In that case you can use reset.css as one of your css stylesheet, This will removes all default properties of elements. add this code in reset.css file : link         ----- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset